# Regex to get part of a String

Tags: javascript, regex

`String str` is set to:

```
{"query":{"count":1,"created":"2012-02-26T21:38:27Z","lang":"en-US","results":{"title":"Google Search"}}}
```

I want to use Regex to get `Google Search`. The `2012-02-26T21:38:27Z` and `en-US` are variable.

This is going to happen in Javascript.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just parse the JSON string and use the resulting data structure to get at the string that you need?

Comment: Are you using a helper library, such as jQuery?

Comment: No; you want to use a JSON parser.

Comment: For some reason I thought that was a String. So thanks folks. Using the JOSN parser is much cleaner!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a JSON string, so parse it as such:

```
JSON.parse(str).query.results.title
```

Answer (score 4):

That is a JSON string, so you don't want to use a regex. Instead:

```
var obj = window.JSON.parse(str);
var title = obj.query.results.title;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you would find it much easier using a [JSON parser](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) to get the information that you want. As mentioned by others here, you could use something like the following to get what you're after.

```
JSON.parse(str).query.results.title
```

If for some reason you absolutely have to use a RegExp though, you could try something like:

```
function parseStr(str) {
    var re, matches;
    re = /"results":{"title":"([^"]*)"}/;
    matches = str.match(re);
    if (matches && matches.length > 1) {
        return matches[1];
    }
}
```